# Grails groovy.lang.MissingMethodException. shoppingCartService.addToShoppingCart(summary.items[partId].item, delta) throws MethodMissingException

Tags: grails

```
def shoppingCartService

def produceShoppingCartInfo(){
    def shoppingItems = shoppingCartService.getItems()
    def summary = new ShoppingCartSummary(items: [:], total: BigDecimal.ZERO)
    shoppingItems.each { shoppingItem ->
        def part = Shoppable.findByShoppingItem(shoppingItem)
        def quantity = new BigDecimal(shoppingCartService.getQuantity(part))
        BigDecimal lineTotal = part.price.multiply(quantity)
        summary.items[part.id] = new Expando(quantity:quantity, item:part, lineTotal:lineTotal)
        summary.total = summary.total.add(lineTotal)
    }
    summary
}

def updateCartQuantities(newQuantities) {
    def summary =  produceShoppingCartInfo()
    newQuantities.each {  
        def partId = it.key
        def newQuantity = it.value
        if(summary.items[partId]) {
            def currentQuantity = summary.items[partId].quantity
            def delta = newQuantity - currentQuantity
            if(delta > 0) {
                shoppingCartService.addToShoppingCart(summary.items[partId].item, delta)
//              shoppingCartService.addToShoppingCart(summary.items[partId].item)
            } else if (delta < 0) {
                shoppingCartService.removeFromShoppingCart(summary.items[partId].item, Math.abs(delta))
//              shoppingCartService.removeFromShoppingCart(summary.items[partId].item)
            }
        }
    }
    produceShoppingCartInfo()

}

def getTotalItemsForCart(){
    def summary =  produceShoppingCartInfo()
    def totalItems = 0

    summary.items.each { partId, itemInfo  ->
        def currentItemQuantity = itemInfo.quantity
        totalItems = totalItems+currentItemQuantity
    }

    totalItems

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: shoppingCartService.addToShoppingCart(summary.items[partId].item, delta)   This line throws MissingMethodException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you're not passing the correct arguments to `addToShoppingCart`. It expects `IShoppable` and `Integer`.

```
def addToShoppingCart(IShoppable product, Integer qty = 1, ShoppingCart previousShoppingCart = null)
```

Your domain class implements `IShoppable`? Are you passing the domain instance as first argument?

Source of the plugin service [here](https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-shopping-cart/trunk/grails-app/services/com/metasieve/shoppingcart/ShoppingCartService.groovy).

**EDIT**

Your problem is probably with the type of your variables. In this case is better to use a concrete type instead of the Groovy `def`.

```
def delta = newQuantity - currentQuantity
println delta.class.name //here you will see if this is really a Integer
```

You probably want something like:

```
Integer delta = newQuantity.asInteger() - currentQuantity.asInteger()
```

Choose to use `def` only when you don't need to know the type of the object. If you know that this is a `Long`, `Integer`, `BigDecimal` and etc, tend to declare your variable with the type.

Comment: Yes domain instance is the first argument

Comment: shoppingCartService.removeFromShoppingCart(summary.items[partId].item, Math.abs(delta))            shoppingCartService.removeFromShoppingCart(summary.items[partId].item) The second line of code works fine, but that's is not what I wanted, because it neither update nor remove from the cart.

Comment: Math.abs returns a `Double` and the method expects an `Integer`.

Comment: This is confusing to me now. Can you please explain how can I make this code work? Any explanation would be much helpful to me this time.

Comment: Math.abs(delta) is Integer java.lang.Math.abs(int a) which returns absolute value of an int value. Link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: delta is of type java.math.BigDecimal and with that change I am getting " NumberFormatException Message: for input String: "1B" ".

Comment: Since it's a BigDecimal you can use `intVal()`.

Comment: BigInteger delta = newQUnatity - currentQuantity solved the problem. The problem now is, while updating the cart with whole decimal empty's the cart.